# SublimeText3 | API Injected completions

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

SublimeText: This doc https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/completions.html talks about API-injected completions.

My requirement is as follows

```
ParentFolder
 Folder1
   file1.json
   file2.json
   file3.json
MainFile.json
```

Ctrl+Tab in MainFile.json should prompt me file1, file2, file3 as auto-complete options.

How do I do this working with API-injected completions? I couldnt see any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*API-injected* completions are completions that are added to the list on the fly by packages. For this you must hook to the `on_query_completions` event.

Here is a simple package that will help you to get started: https://github.com/Zinggi/DictionaryAutoComplete